# How use subqueues of entityqueue module?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, 9

I'm on D9 and already using [entityqueue](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityqueue) module to let the content editors orders some views via *"simple"* queues

Now, I've been requested to make possible to order the nodes appearing on the terms' pages of a specific taxonomy.

Those pages - on `/taxonomy/term/%` url - are rendered trough the "standard" solution of a view of content with a contextual filter *"Has taxonomy term ID"*.

I've successfully tried to create a "smart-queue" of taxonomy term with the *Entityqueue Smartqueue* submodule: this actually create a queue with N sub-queues for each term.

However, I can't understand how should configure the original view to show the nodes according the relative sub-queue. I can add the "entity subqueue" relationship only if the "entityqueue" relationship is present, that causes anyway the following error in the view preview.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'items_node_field_data__entity_subqueue__items.items_target_id_export' in 'on clause': SELECT "node_field_data"."langcode" AS "node_field_data_langcode", "node_field_data"."created" AS "node_field_data_created", "node_field_data"."nid" AS "nid", "items_node_field_data"."name" AS "items_node_field_data_name", "entity_subqueue_field_data_entity_subqueue__items"."name" AS "entity_subqueue_field_data_entity_subqueue__items_name" FROM "node_field_data" "node_field_data" INNER JOIN "entity_subqueue__items" "entity_subqueue__items" ON node_field_data.nid = CAST(entity_subqueue__items.items_target_id AS UNSIGNED) AND entity_subqueue__items.bundle = :views_join_condition_0 INNER JOIN "entity_subqueue_field_data" "items_node_field_data" ON entity_subqueue__items.entity_id = items_node_field_data.name LEFT JOIN "entity_subqueue__items" "items_node_field_data__entity_subqueue__items" ON items_node_field_data.name = items_node_field_data__entity_subqueue__items.entity_id AND items_node_field_data__entity_subqueue__items.deleted = :views_join_condition_1 INNER JOIN "entity_subqueue_field_data" "entity_subqueue_field_data_entity_subqueue__items" ON items_node_field_data__entity_subqueue__items.items_target_id_export = entity_subqueue_field_data_entity_subqueue__items.name LEFT JOIN "taxonomy_index" "taxonomy_index" ON node_field_data.nid = taxonomy_index.nid WHERE ("node_field_data"."langcode" IN (:db_condition_placeholder_2)) AND ("taxonomy_index"."status" = :db_condition_placeholder_3) ORDER BY "node_field_data_created" DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => it [:db_condition_placeholder_3] => 1 [:views_join_condition_0] => test_ [:views_join_condition_1] => 0 )

Is possible to get the result with entityqueue? How?

[image]